# Select joined tables in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table:

```
Shop (ShopID, ShopName)
```

and a table

```
Campaign (CampaignID, CampaignName)
```

which have a many to many relation. Entity Framework creates a join table `CampaignShop` with `(ShopID, CampaignID)` for me. However the table is not exposed by EF and I can't use it in LINQ statements.

How Can I query all shops with given `campaignID`?

If I try

```
dbContext.MerchantShop
    .Where(c => c.Campaign.CampaignID == campaignID)
```

`Campaign.CampaignID` is not working.

Comment: What error do you get? Or do you just not see any results?

Comment: Sounds strange. Because when it's purely a couple table (for the many-to-many relationship) it should be converted into Navigation properties for Shop(.Campaigns) as well as for Campaign(.Shops). Did you include foreign keys in the generation of the Entity model?

Comment: You need to dbContext.MerchantShop.Include("Campaign").Where(c => c.Campaign.CampaignID == campaignID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx) extension method.

```
 dbContext.MerchantShop
    .Where(s => s.Campaign.Any(c => c.CampaignID == campaignID));
```